# folium 0.4 cannot work : TypeError: choropleth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'geo_path'

Tags: python, folium

I am reading Alexander T. Combs
's book- [Python Machine Learning Blueprints: Intuitive data projects you can relate to.](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/python-machine-learning-blueprints-intuitive-data-projects-you-ca)

There are some questions on ch2.The code on the book:

```
map = folium.Map(location=[40.748817, -73.985428], zoom_start=13)
map.geo_json(geo_path=r'/Users/alexcombs/Downloads/nyc.json', data=su_lt_two,
             columns=['Zip', 'Rent'],
             key_on='feature.properties.postalCode',
             threshold_scale=[1700.00, 1900.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2500.00, 2750.00],
             fill_color='YlOrRd', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
             legend_name='Rent (%)',
              reset=True)
map.create_map(path='nyc.html')
```

My code:

```
map = folium.Map(location=[40.748817, -73.985428], zoom_start=13)

nyc = r'nyc.json'

map.choropleth(geo_path = nyc, data=su_lt_two,columns=['zip', 'Rent'],
               key_on='Feature.properties.postalCode',
               threshold_scale=[1700.00, 1900.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2500.00, 2750.00],
               fill_color='YlOrRd', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
               legend_name='Rent (%)',reset=True)

map.create_map(path='nyc.html')
```

and I got a Typeerror:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-420abe6d80fb> in <module>()
      8                threshold_scale=[1700.00, 1900.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2500.00, 2750.00],
      9                fill_color='YlOrRd', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
---> 10                legend_name='Rent (%)',reset=True)
     11 
     12 map.create_map(path='nyc.html')

TypeError: choropleth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'geo_path'
```

[nyc.json file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fecxo6aae67ocv4/nyc.json?dl=0)

Answer (score 3):

There were some [api changes](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/CHANGES.txt) with 0.4.

Here's the one that causing your error

> - `choropleth` now takes a single `geo_data` instad of `geo_path`/`geo_str`   leaving the parsing to `GeoJSON`

Try this

```
map.choropleth(geo_data = nyc, data=su_lt_two,columns=['zip', 'Rent'],
               key_on='Feature.properties.postalCode',
               threshold_scale=[1700.00, 1900.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2500.00, 2750.00],
               fill_color='YlOrRd', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
               legend_name='Rent (%)',reset=True)
```